# Creating user info bean in JBoss

Tags: java, spring, portlet, jboss-portal

I'm a little bit stuck in a problem right now: I've got a `JBoss Portal` which runs on a `JBoss AS 4.2.3`. There are running some webapps on the machine which provide some portlets to users. Now I need a centralized solution:

Every time an user logs in I want to create a `session bean` where some user information is hold. I'm using spring in all my webapps - as some extra information.

How can I achieve this? This session bean must be created asap when a login occurs - so I can catch it safely from my spring apps.

Several thoughts:

- Is there a possibility to recognize a login via a listener?
- Should I use a filter and check if `request.getRemoteUser()` isn't null?

Answer (score 0):

maybe smth like 
      `<bean id="userInfo" class="com.s.userInfo" scope="session"/>` in application-context? 'Session' can be changed with 'conversation', maybe.

Comment: Well my main problem is that I'm in a portal enviorment so that logins don't happen in my apps.